# Cookie Storage on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, queue, task

Extreme newbie, apologize in advance, I have no idea what I'm doing -- but  I really have looked around.

I am downloading a few dozen pages behind a login form and dbing the results, running on GAE.  I would like to enqueue each page read and database write in the task queue.  When I changed over to task queue, I realized I had problems passing my session around.

I create an opener using urllib2:

```
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    session = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    session.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))  
    login_data = urllib.urlencode({ 'username' : 'guest',
                                    'password' : 'guest',
                                    'Submit1'  : 'Submit'})  
    resp = session.open(self.login_page, login_data, timeout=20) 
    self.session = session
```

Previously I was only instantiating this class once at the head end of things, creating one session instance variable for everyone to use, and then passing my instantiation around to keep context.  Using task queue I cannot pass objects, so when my request handler gets called, I can't give him reference to the opener or the cookie.

Is there a way to store or pass the opener, or the cookie info so that I can build a new opener without logging in again each time?  Can I pass cookie information through the headers dictionary to each handler?  Stuff something in memcache? What exactly do I need to pass to get the cookie back into a valid opener?

Many thanks to anyone who wades through the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass objects via [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) instead of taskqueue.

But for reliability reason, I recommand you to store your objects in datastore and only pass there reference in taskqueue.

Comment: It just dawned on me what pickle is all about...I didnt realize I could reconstitute something like a class instance from a database.  That is very cool.  I will try putting it to the db and passing a reference.

Comment: @user1354036 Just don't let the power all go to your head. ;) There are some things pickle is good for, like this (at least arguably), and others it's not, like user data. Personally, I don't think there's a good reason to store the cookies in the datastore - a reference won't be much smaller than the cookie itself.